# Getting PhaseScriptExecution Bundle\ errors when trying to build using EAS / Expo

Tags: react-native, build, expo

I've been having issues getting a successful build for a project I'm working on. I keep getting the following error:

```
 ** ARCHIVE FAILED **
▸ The following build commands failed:
▸   PhaseScriptExecution Bundle\ React\ Native\ code\ and\ images /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Brainiac-engdhxyrndsxydamdhbacjdwwrlk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Brainiac/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Brainiac.build/Release-iphoneos/Brainiac.build/Script-00DD1BFF1BD5951E006B06BC.sh (in target 'Brainiac' from project 'Brainiac')
▸ (1 failure)
** ARCHIVE FAILED **
The following build commands failed:
    PhaseScriptExecution Bundle\ React\ Native\ code\ and\ images /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Brainiac-engdhxyrndsxydamdhbacjdwwrlk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Brainiac/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Brainiac.build/Release-iphoneos/Brainiac.build/Script-00DD1BFF1BD5951E006B06BC.sh (in target 'Brainiac' from project 'Brainiac')
(1 failure)
```

I've done searches here and tried suggestions in threads but still having trouble eliminating these. Currently running expo-cli 6.1.0 and expo sdk 44. Project is using Node 16.9.0. Any help is appreciated!